# Import a npm module, written in js, in Angular 2 component?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular, telegram-bot

I explain myself better: I want to use `node-telegram-bot-api`, a npm module for Node, to control my bot on Telegram messenger.

```
npm install node-telegram-bot-api
```

This is the example to use it on Node, completely in Javascript:
How can I import the module in a Angular 2 component, and within the export class, call it the functions, like in the example?

```
var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

var token = 'YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN';
// Setup polling way
var bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

// Matches /echo [whatever]
bot.onText(/\/echo (.+)/, function (msg, match) {
  var fromId = msg.from.id;
  var resp = match[1];
  bot.sendMessage(fromId, resp);
});
```

The module is on Github [here](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/).

Tell me if I'm getting something wrong since I'm still a beginner in Angular 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry men, but you can't import directly that library into Angular2 or other library in the client side.

That is because that is a NodeJs module and use several native modules from nodejs.

If you want use that module, you must create a server in NodeJs and implement the logic for comunicate the server to the clients, maybe whit webSockets o something like that or found a implementation in client side.

I wish you luck.